# ActiveMQ InactivityMonitor Weird Issue

Tags: activemq-classic

We are facing a strange issue at one of our customers.
We are using ActiveMQ v 5.11.1

Our broker uri in the 'active.xml' file is as below:-

```
<"ssl://0.0.0.0:50020?maximumConnections=10000&wireformat.maxFrameSize=104857600">
```

Our client side uri is as below:-

```
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("ssl://queueIpAddress:queuePortNumber?wireFormat.cacheEnabled=false&wireFormat.tightEncodingEnabled=true&wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration=30000")
connection = connectionFactory.createConnection()
```

The 'InactivityMonitor' is working as expected. But we have observed the below message in the log file

```
2015-12-10 16:12:10,410 [DEBUG] (InactivityMonitor) – 0 ms elapsed since last write check.
2015-12-10 16:12:10,410 [DEBUG] (InactivityMonitor) – 0 ms elapsed since last write check.
2015-12-10 16:12:10,410 [DEBUG] (InactivityMonitor) – 0 ms elapsed since last write check.
2015-12-10 16:12:10,410 [DEBUG] (InactivityMonitor) – 0 ms elapsed since last write check.
2015-12-10 16:12:10,411 [DEBUG] (InactivityMonitor) – 1 ms elapsed since last write check.
2015-12-10 16:12:10,412 [DEBUG] (InactivityMonitor) – 2 ms elapsed since last write check.
2015-12-10 16:12:10,412 [DEBUG] (InactivityMonitor) – 1 ms elapsed since last write check.
2015-12-10 16:12:10,412 [DEBUG] (InactivityMonitor) – 0 ms elapsed since last write check.
2015-12-10 16:12:10,412 [DEBUG] (InactivityMonitor) – 0 ms elapsed since last write check.
2015-12-10 16:12:10,412 [DEBUG] (InactivityMonitor) – 0 ms elapsed since last write check.
2015-12-10 16:12:10,412 [DEBUG] (InactivityMonitor) – 0 ms elapsed since last write check.
2015-12-10 16:12:10,412 [DEBUG] (InactivityMonitor) – 0 ms elapsed since last write check..
```

The above message is printed continuously in the log file and the log file grows very fast within few seconds. We want to understand in what scenario this will happen?

**At the same time we have observed that the bandwidth usage is very high in the network during this time.**

We did not find any clue why this suddenly happens and this is very critical for us to resolve. This issue is happening very rarely but the impact is very high because of high bandwidth usage.

Thanks in advance!!